# Google Meet ling doesnt work when created with Calendar API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I want to create a link to Google meet in Google calendar, here is my code. It turns out that the link appears in the calendar, but it does not work. Could it be that I use a service account for the calendar?

```
const event = {
    hangoutLink: `https://meet.google.com/${meetURL}`,
    start: {
      dateTime: startDateTime,
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endDateTime,
    },
    summary: eventSummary,
    description: eventDescription,
    visibility: 'public',
    conferenceData: {
      conferenceId: meetURL,
        entryPoints: [
        {
          entryPointType: "video",
          uri: `https://meet.google.com/${meetURL}`,
          label: `meet.google.com/${meetURL}`
        }
      ],
      conferenceSolution: {
        key: {
          type: "hangoutsMeet"
        }
      },
      attendees: [
        {email: userCalendarId}
      ]
    },
  }
```

If i add "createRequest" the link is not created in the calendar.
If i added MeetType like this:

```
"conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            },
```

I will receive "Invalid conference type value".

[created meet in calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu4GR.png)